# Converting GEDCOM to KML?

Tags: kml, google-earth, software-recommendations, genealogy, gedcom

Does anyone know of a way to convert GEDCOM files to KML?

I am building a family tree and I would like to be able to upload the infromation I have gathered to Google Earth.

I already tried to use GedGenie but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gedcomtokml/

should do the GEDCOM to KML conversion.

You can find the info on it here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_My_Ancestors

It seems straightforward enough.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunatelly, "Map My Ancestors" (which would be the solution to my problems) is not available anymore. Here is the announcement: http://www.familytreeassistant.com/ GedcomToKml is a JAR archives which, no matter what I tried, refuses to run. If there is anyone out there with an idea on that please help!

Comment: Apologies you are correct, it is dead.

Answer (score 0):

At the [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/tracking-family-names-and-migration-patterns-using-gis/1458#1458) I just found that:

> There is a software program called Family Atlas ([www.familyatlas.com](http://www.rootsmagic.com/family-atlas/))
>   that will import data from a variety of sources, including GEDCOM. If
>   the coordinate of an event place is included, it will use it.
>   Otherwise it will look up a coordinate based on the place name.
>
> It has a variety of basic mapping capabilities but, in line with what
>   you're asking, it can export the data to a KML file which you can use
>   in most web and desktop GIS applications.

Answer (score 0):

The [GRAMPS](https://gramps-project.org/) open source genealogy project has some GIS related features.

It can read and write GEDCOM files, and is able to geocode place names with Openstreetmap`s nominatim or Google Maps (if you have an account at Google).

The export to CSV creates a table with places and their coordinates for use in GIS software. If you have Google Earth installed, you can export to KML as well with an addon (though I have not tested that). Apart from that, you can export the data to sqlite and work on with that.

The software runs on Windows and Linux, and is free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

While Gramps exports a csv file it is not, at least for me, useable directly by google maps. The table created is a variable table that is then inserted into the contacts(ancestors) row of information. From my experience GM simply wants name, address, geo coordinates etc., not a variable name.